# Database error (server error) while deploying mobilefisrt artifacts

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, mobilefirst-server

I have deployed IBM mobilefirst 7.1 application on IBM mobilefirst server using server configuration tool. My application server is Websphere application server 8.0(Network deployment) with a single node cluster.

When I tries to deploy application on Mobilefirst console, Ii is giving me error :

FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
FWLSE3010E: A database error was detected.

I am accessing mobilefirst console using localhost on same machine.

My server Logs :

```
ServiceProxy  E   Received status 500 for POST https://localhost:9443/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MYMobile71/applications?async=true
                                 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://localhost:9443/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MYMobile71/applications?async=true
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:453)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1530)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://localhost:9443/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MYMobile71/applications?async=true
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1481)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:51)
    at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:164)
    ... 30 more

ServiceProxy  E   Exception Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://localhost:9443/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MYMobile71/applications?async=true while redirecting request to https://localhost:9443/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MYMobile71/applications?async=true
```

Project wlapp and adapter deployment both are giving same error.
Is there configuration required for deploying mobilefirst artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the outset it seems like an installation issue. Looks like Admin service is failing and may be related to Database connection (FWLSE3010E — mentioned above) etc…

You can verify the same by logging in to WAS Admin console and verify for the datasource (testconnection) and also see if services (Admin/Runtime) are running.

Unless we see the full logs we can’t pinpoint the problem.